# Laravel 8 - Run Route Middleware before Constructor

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel v8.35. I have created a middleware `EnsureTokenIsValid` and registered it in `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'valid.token' => \App\Http\Middleware\EnsureTokenIsValid::class,
];
```

Here is the middleware itself:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class EnsureTokenIsValid
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->input('token') !== 'my-secret-token') {
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Essentially this middleware will redirect the user to a login page if the token is not valid. Now I want this middleware to run on specific routes. So I tried doing this:

```
Route::get('/', [IndexController::class, 'index'])->middleware('valid.token');
```

However it seems the code in the constructor of the parent controller (`app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php`) is being called first. My controllers all extend from this parent controller, e.g:

```
class IndexController extends Controller
```

I have tried putting the middleware at the very beginning in the constructor of `Controller.php`, but that does not work either, i.e. it just proceeds to the next line without performing the redirect:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('valid.token');

    // code here which should not run if the above middleware performs a redirect
    $this->userData = session()->get('userData');
    
    // Error occurs here if 'userData' is null
    if ($this->userData->username) {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

If I put the middleware in my `IndexController` constructor, it works. However I don't want to do this for every controller - I just want the middleware to exist in the parent controller.

Comment: Middlewares are executed before controllers. Your middleware should have a different issue. Please share its code.

Comment: The framework has to instantiate your controller (constructor is called) because it needs to know if you have defined any middleware in the constructor so it will create the controller before the request has gone through the middleware stack to that middleware .... if this is a problem you are most likely doing something in the constructor that shouldn't be there, or should be done in a "controller middleware" in the constructor

Comment: since what you want to do is dependent upon other middleware being ran what ever code is in the constructor should be another middleware so it runs in the stack

Comment: @lagbox I have just updated my code, basically I do a check in the session for a variable called `userData` - this can be an object or null. When it's null I get an error. I know I can do a stricter check for that, but I prefer something more cleaner. Ideally it shouldn't be attempting to run that code at all. Thanks.

Comment: @lagbox this is a really annoying bug in my opinion. Route middlewares should trigger before the Controller is constructed for the reason that they execute BEFORE the controller to know how to execute the controller in the correct way. Then is there are other Controller middleware, they can be triggered afterwards. But to group all the route and controller middleware into one group and trigger them after construction. Is a bug and it should be fixed

Comment: @bulent actually, in recent version of laravel, at least higher than 8, the controller is constructed before any of the middleware is run. I don't know why they do it this way. I think it's a bug

Comment: @ChristopherThomas its not a bug as this works the way it was designed to work ... luckily it is a simple method to achieve the result needed by working within the stack and the reason why this behavior exists is pretty straightforward

Comment: Just because something is working as designed, does not mean that this design is good. It can be working exactly as specified. Just that this specification is wrong and broken. Just like calling something a middleware, but then executing it AFTER the controller is constructed. Then it's not a middleware anymore. It's similar in functionality. But it's not a middleware. It's something else. So with that said, what is the reason that Laravel creates the controller and executes the middleware afterwards, in the same lifecycle period as the controller middleware?

Comment: @ChristopherThomas because you can define middleware at the controller level not just at the route definition (which requires getting an instance of the controller to get that information from it) ... and it is still a middleware, the middleware is in a stack; so it needs to get the data from the controller to build that stack **before** passing the request through the middleware stack ... without doing this you would never be able to define middleware at the controller level and there would be no controller middleware (which is an important thing)

Comment: ok, so the problem is easy to fix, have the route middleware run before the controller is constructed and have controller middleware run after the controller is constructed. Then you get to have expected behaviour in all scenarios. Route middleware are based on the route and run after the router is ready. Controller middleware are based on the controller and therefore do the same, it runs after the constructed is created and run

Comment: Looks like this issue might be getting fixed after a short conversation with them about it, somebody made a PR for it already: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/44192

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `web` middleware group assigned to this route it doesn't have access to the session in the constructor of your controller any way. You will need to use another middleware or a closure based middleware in the constructor so that it will run in the middleware stack, not when the constructor is ran:

```
protected $userData;

public function __construct(...)
{
    ...

    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->userData = session()->get('userData');

        if ($this->userData && $this->userData->username) {
            // not sure what you need to be doing
        }

        // let the request continue through the stack
        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So, I've also run into this problem and from debugging through the laravel framework code. It runs all the global middleware, then gathers the router middleware, constructs the controller, then afterwards runs all the middleware from the router + all the controller middleware configured in the controller constructor.

I personally think this is a bug, but that doesn't really help you since you need a solution and not just complaining.

Basically, your route no doubt targets a method on the controller, put all your dependencies into that function call and any code that relies upon it into that function call too.

If you need to share a common set of code which runs for each method in that controller, just create a private method and call it from each of the methods.

My problem was that I was using the constructor for dependency injection, like we are all expected to do, since a fully constructed object should have all it's dependencies resolved so you don't end up in a half constructed object state where depending on the function calls, depends on whether you have all the dependencies or not. Which is bad.

However, controller methods are a little different than what you'd consider a typical object or service. They are effectively called as endpoints. So perhaps it's acceptable, in a roundabout way, to consider them not like functions of an object. But using (abusing perhaps), PHP classes to group together methods of related functionality merely for convenience because you can autoload PHP classes, but not PHP functions.

Therefore, maybe the better way to think about this is to be a little permissive about what we would typically do with object construction.

Controller methods, are effectively callbacks for the router to trigger when a router is hit. The fact that they are in an object is for convenience because of autoloading. Therefore we should not treat the constructor in the same way we might for a service. But treat each controller endpoint method as the constructor itself and ignore the constructor except for some situations where you know you can do certain things safely.

But in all other cases, you can't use the constructor in the normal way, because of how the framework executes. So therefore we have to make this little accommodation.

I think it's a bug and personally I think it should be fixed. Maybe it will. But for today, with laravel 9, it's still working like this and I think this at least will help to guide people who ran into the same problem.